# OpenGL shading language best practices

Tags: opengl

I´m writing a little OpenGL Engine 3D in C++ and Eclipse/Visual C++. In outline, my engine has several objects derived from typical GameObject virtual class. In my hierarchy there is several levels depending if the object has children and parent. For example, the terrain object is in the level 0. A tank loaded from blender is in the level 1, Etc.

The question is what is the best practice for rendering each object depending on the corresponding shader. If I have a list of objects renderer by the same shader program, I should render all objects VAOs between the clausules: glUseProgram(program_id) ... glUseProgram(0) instead of change the program for each object. I.e:

```
for each object
glUseProgram(object.program)
  ...
  glBindVertexArray(m_pVao->m_vaoHandle);
  for (GLuint i = 0; i < (m_iNumIndex / 3); i++)
  {
    offset = i * 3;
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &m_Index[offset]);
  }
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Or:

```
glUseProgram(object.program)
  ...
  for each object in program.list
    glBindVertexArray(object.m_pVao->m_vaoHandle);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < (m_iNumIndex / 3); i++)
    {
      offset = i * 3;
      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &m_Index[offset]);
    }
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Sorry the pseudo-pseudocode.

The objects could be stored in std::vector and every shader have a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do the most costly operations (binding programs, shaders, textures, etc.) as little as possible. So, if your design allows it, do binding outside of the loop and reuse the resource. That's one of the most basic performance optimizations you would do later anyway.